# Can we change SHELL env variable and interpreter after executing script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have 2 questions:

1. I have a script `buildllt` which uses `#!/bin/sh`. So, if I run the script using: `/bin/bash buildllt`. What shell interpreter will the OS use? `sh` or `bash`
2. If after running the script using default shell `sh`, can we export `SHELL` 
   env variable as `export SHELL = /bin/bash`? Will the next statements be interpreted using a different shell?

Comment: Related, you should use `#!/usr/bin/env sh`, `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, `#!/usr/bin/env python`, `#!/usr/bin/env python2`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you run the script using `/bin/bash buildllt` then the `#!` line will be ignored and `bash` will be used.
2. No. `SHELL` is set by a shell as the name of the login shell, it is not read. Even if it was read, exporting it would not affect the parent process. If you want to run an interactive bash session then just type `bash` or even `exec bash` to replace your previous `sh` program.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your questions:

1. If you run an interpreter explicitly, then the shebang will not be taken into account. So `/bin/bash buildllt` will be run by `/bin/bash` regardless of the shebang.
2. The `SHELL` environment variable is set to the preferred shell that is indicated in the `/etc/passwd` file (see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Other_environment_variables)). This should be the shell invoked when the user logs in, but will not be used to execute any scripts. The shebang is used for that.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a script `buildllt` which uses `#!/bin/sh`. So, if I run the script using `/bin/bash buildllt`. What shell interpreter will the OS use? `sh` or `bash`

Of course `/bin/bash`. The shebang is for the OS to determine which interpreter to use **when the script file is executed directly**, i.e. when you run `./buildllt`. The operating system will read the first line and choose a interpreter for the script. If you invoke `bash buildllt` then the OS simply executes `bash` and supply the script as an argument, then `bash` will ignore the shebang line (because it starts with a hash which is considered as comment).

[See more about shebang on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

> If after running the script using default shell sh, can we export `SHELL` env variable as `export SHELL = /bin/bash`

Yes, but it won't have any effect. The `SHELL` environment variable is to determine which shell to be used as a user's login shell. It's specified in `/etc/passwd` and is only effective with shell login (like `su user` or when you log in from a terminal, no effect when logging in with a desktop environment like GNOME). Even if you change it, later scripts won't be affected. They are still run with the interpreter specified by their shebang lines. You surely don't want a Python script `#!/usr/bin/python3` to be run by `bash`, right?

BTW, as *tripleee* pointed out, `export` does not accept spaces around the equal sign. You need to write this to make it work.

```
export SHELL=/bin/bash
```

Comment: Maybe also point out the syntax error in the `export` -- it won't work with whitespace around the equals sign.

Comment: @tripleee Good spot.